# adding Css and js file to content page

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb.net website. In this website i have master page and content page.when i am adding CSS and JS file to master page it's
working perfect. it is also working when i am give this CSS to another default page so it will be not execution problem of CSS and JS file.Now,my problem is when i am add CSS file and JS file in the content place holder of the content page it is not working. so where i can put this file so it will be be work?  I have searching on many places but i cant get the proper answer from anywhere.

Comment: Please edit your post with the relevant code that's not working, and tell us what actually happens: Does it give an error? Does it do anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be working, as long as the file is there in the view source. If the tag isn't there, then you have an other problem.

An other option is to put a content place holder in the head (or footer) of your master page.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And then inside the content page put your file there.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="contentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
    ... put <style and <script here.
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: i am put content placeholder in head section of master page. and i have all the files of CSS and JS still it  is not working.

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati do you see them when you do view source?

Comment: from where I can view source?? I am new in this. so, I don't know somethings.

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati in the browser, do a view source.

Comment: no there is no source for which i needed.actually i want to add text editor which is in my template so,this is not appear in to my web form.actually it is plugin into plugins of text editor which is not shown in web form.